# Class inheritance and custom ^block execution in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, block, afnetworking

I have an app in which I have a call to a webservice to retrieve a JSON object with a given id.
Whatever the class I am in, the method to get the object will be systematically the same, but the success block will differ (id est, the processing part) - using AFNetworking for instance.

I am looking for proper way to implement only once the getter part but to be able to customize the processing.

Is the following piece of code a good approach :

```
   -(void)getObjectWithId:(NSString*)id_{

    NSString *ns1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",HOSTNAME,API_DETAIL,id_];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ns1]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {


        //Here I want to do different processing task accordingly inheritance level // current class

        DLog(@"Response : %@ \n Request : %@",response,request);

        [self processObject:JSON];


    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        //Do failure stuff

    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

and then :

```
-(void)processObject:(id)JSON{


    //Customize according to current class

}
```

Consequently, all subclasses will inherit from `getObjectWithId` and have their own implementation of `processObject`

What should I also consider ? Is is a proper way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option will work, but it is restrictive putting the code in a superclass. If the restriction is fine for you then go ahead.

An alternative would be to create a helper method or manager class which hosted the `getObjectWithId:` method, but to supply 2 parameters where the second parameter is a block which takes the JSON as a parameter. In this way the method contains all of the reusable code and the block allows for the same arbitrary usage as the original AFNetworking API.

Note, the 'proper way' is whatever works for your situation and is also understandable and maintainable...

Comment: Thanks, after reviewing at a high level my code, I think I will use class in my singleton Manager which is appropriate (I think) to wrap a getter method, and pass a block as a paramater which takes the JSON. Sounds nice !

Answer (score 1):

No need to use subclassing. Delegate will help you.

You can create a utility class to retrieve a JSON object and declare a protocol for it.

```
@protocol WebServiceDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didRetrivalJsonObject:(id)json ;
@end
```

You also need to modify the method

```
- (void)getObjectWithId:(NSString*)id_ delegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)delegate
{
    NSString *ns1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",HOSTNAME,API_DETAIL,id_];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ns1]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //Here I want to do different processing task accordingly inheritance level // current class
        DLog(@"Response : %@ \n Request : %@",response,request);
        [delegate processObject:JSON];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        //Do failure stuff
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: I will consider the approach below, but thanks, this seems quite cool too